# How to select distinct on a col using linq/projection?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

How can I get the following to work with distinct on the x.name?

```
var x= db.Cs.Select(x => new{name=x.name,id=x.id}).Distinct().ToList();
```

Per the following example data:

```
name, id
joe, 1
joe, 2
joe, 3
```

I get the entire set back using the distinct query above:

```
name, id
joe, 1
joe, 2
joe, 3
```

What I really want is obviously one unique row but I still want an identifier back as well (i.e.):

```
name, id
joe, 1
```

Comment: Take the minimum id then take the distincts of all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) method:

```
var x = db.Cs.Select(x => new { x.name, x.id}).GroupBy(x => x.name);
```

Then you will get a dictionary where the key will be the name and the value your projection.

Or if you really want to use a distinct, you can write your own [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) and use the correct [Distinct overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Just to complete Stephane's post. The result of his code is an IGrouping.... If you want your id/name annonymous type, just add this:

```
var x = db.Cs.Select(x => new { x.name, x.id})
            .GroupBy(x => x.name)
            .Select(g => g.First())
```